# How to fit dated stock market data with non-linear model fit?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, syntax

I am new to Mathematica and I am currently doing a project on predicting stock market trends using log-periodic power law. I am trying to fit stock market data to the following equation. y(t) = A + B (tc − t)^z + C (tc − t)^z*cos (ω log (tc − t) + Φ) https://www2.math.su.se/matstat/reports/serieb/2009/rep7/report.pdf Page 5

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Data,A + B (tc - t)^z + (c (tc - t)^z)*(Cos (\[Omega]*Log (tc - t) +[Phi])), {A, B, tc, z,c, \[Omega], \[Phi]}, t]
```

"Data" is a dated stock market data for Dow Jones Index Average I am not sure exactly why this did not work. I figure it should be something to do with the data being dated and I am not sure how to handle dated data.

This is the Output I got

NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {-16007.8+1. (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.+1. Cos (1. +1. Log (1. -1. DateObject[<<4>>])) (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.,-15913.6+1. (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.+1. Cos (1. +1. Log (1. -1. DateObject[<<4>>])) (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.,-15888.8+1. (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.+1. Cos (1. +1. Log (1. -1. DateObject[<<4>>])) (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.,<<46>>,-15793.1+1. (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.+1. Cos (1. +1. Log (1. -1. DateObject[<<4>>])) (1. -1. DateObject[{<<6>>},Instant,Gregorian,8.])^1.,<<1255>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {1305} at {A,B,tc,z,c,[Omega],[Phi]} = {1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.}.

Edit One error I realized. I used the wrong brackets. New Input

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Data,  A + B[tc - t]^z + [c[tc - t]^z]*[Cos[\[Omega]*Log[tc - t] + \[Phi]]], {A, B, tc,z, c, \[Omega], \[Phi]}, t]`
```

But the output was Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "[c[tc-t]^z][Cos[[Omega]Log[tc-t]+[Phi]]]". Not exactly sure what was wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You have to be careful about your use of square brackets and round brackets! Square brackets define functions, i.e. B[tc-t] implies B is a function (which I think is not what you want try: `A + B (tc - t)^z + (c (tc - t)^z)*(Cos[\[Omega]*Log[tc - t] + \[Phi])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to try.  Compute fits for a range of estimated `tc` dates and see which is the best fit.

```
data = FinancialData["^DJI", "1980-01-01"];
(* convert to OLE day values *)
toOAdate[date_] := QuantityMagnitude[
    DateDifference[{1901, 1, 0}, date]] + 366;
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 1]] = toOAdate /@ data2[[All, 1]];
(* estimate start date of crash (Fitch downgrade of Countrywide) *)
tc = toOAdate["2007-08-16"];
(* select for t < tc so Log[tc - t] stays valid *)
data3 = Select[data2, First[#] < tc &];
(* compute with tc - t as tcminust *)
data3[[All, 1]] = data3[[All, 1]] /. x_Integer :> tc - x;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data3,
   a + b (tcminust)^z + c (tcminust)^z Cos[\[Omega] Log[tcminust] + \[Phi]],
   {a, b, z, c, \[Omega], \[Phi]}, tcminust, MaxIterations -> 1000];
nlm["BestFit"]
```